# Detect if javascript has stopped

Tags: javascript

If I use javascript to do important stuff on the client, how do I warn the user if the javascript engine stops due to a uncaught javascript error?

I am interested in replacing the error handling with my own so I can catch any errors that might occur.

Comment: Because your one liner is normally not enough explanation.

Comment: Do you want to catch the error or to inform the user **about** it?

Comment: Of course questions can be asked in one line. 4 down votes to excellent question! :(

Comment: As you can see from the comments and answers, your question could have benefited from either an example or the distinction between catching ANY error or just a possible error in a localised part of the script :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can intercept errors in many ways. Here is one, based on the very little information you gave in your question

[window.onerror](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers.onerror)

```
window.onerror=function(error,URL,line) {
  alert("An error "+ error +" occurred.");
}
```

> Error message (string).
>
> Url where error was raised (string).
>
> Line number where error was raised (number).

other ways are to wrap "dangerous code" in a [try/catch construct](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch)

Answer (score 4):

Use try and catch

```
try {
   //some code that might cause an error
} catch(e) {
   //if there is an error this code will execute.
}
```

Comment: Sorry, should have wrote "due to a javascript uncaught error".

Comment: if you surround the code with this it will catch any uncaught error. but of course the window.onerror that mplungjan shows is better as its a catch all, and you dont have to write try catches multiple times.

Comment: Yes, but my question was meant for the errors you haven't thought of and therefore could be unhandled.